# Java Color by age

Tags: java, graphics, colors

I'm writing a little app that displays some graphics and just now I'm trying to change the color depending on the age of an Object (saved via `System.currentTimeMillis()`) so the oldest are blue and the newest Objects get displayed Red or so. Does anyone know an algorithm vel ita (or so)?

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually with everything... :D I have no idea how i should start with my calculating algorithm...

Comment: Can you use if/then chain and pick colors by brackets. >1hr, >3hr, >5280hr etc?

Comment: That would be a good idea but i think it's reaaaally undynamic... is there another way maybe? I think some Bit-Operations and the Color(int  rgba)-constructor would be a good idea, but i don't really know anything about Bit-Operations!

Comment: No need for smileys or sigs. in questions.  Please leave them in your profile.

Comment: two downvotes? The question is clear enough, relevant and by judging the OP's reputation, he might legitimately not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want your **oldest** object to be blue, and your **newest** object to be red, and you know all the objects "age" (let's call it `timestamp`)

```
// mesure the difference in age of the newest and oldest objects
double agediff = newest.timestamp - oldest.timestamp;

// for any given object :
// 1. color ratio from 0.0=old to 1.0=new
double ratio = (someObject.timestamp - oldest.timestamp) / ageDiff;

// 2. get red and blue values
int red = 255 - (255 * ratio);
int blue = 255 * ratio;

// 3. construct Color
Color objectColor = new Color(red, 0, blue);
```

If you want to scale the number of shades you want to display, simply round ratio according to a step scale. For example :

```
// the maximum number of shades between blue and red
int step = 4;    // the value cannot be 1 (otherwise use a Color constant!)

double stepScale = 256 / (step - 1);
double halfStepScale = stepScale / 2;
ratio = Math.ceil((int) ((ratio * 256 + halfStepScale) / stepScale) * stepScale) / 256d;
```

Or if, instead, you want to scale from the newest to a max TTL value (for example, `60 seconds`, or `60000 millis`), simply replace `oldest.timestamp` with this value and change your algorithm to include an overflow check :

```
// our "oldest" timestamp is now pre-defined:
long oldestTs = newest.timestamp - ttlTimestamp;  // ttlTimestamp = 60000;
// mesure the difference in age of the newest and the TTL (ex: 60000)
double agediff = newest.timestamp - oldestTs;

// for any given object :
// 1. color ratio from 0.0=old to 1.0=new
double ratio = (someObject.timestamp - oldestTs) / ageDiff;

if (ratio < 0.0) ratio = 0.0;   // prevent overflow

// etc.
```

** **Edit** **

If you want other gradient than blue/red, you can have :

```
// green=new, yellow=old
new Color(1f - (float) ratio, 1f, 0f);
// yellow=new, green=old
new Color((float) ratio, 1f, 0f);
// green=new, red=old
new Color(1f - (float) ratio, (float) ratio, 0f);

// etc.
```

Comment: Okay thank you very very much! I used your first excerpt and now i only got a little question left: how am i able to use 2 Color-Objects instead of the hardcoded color-values?

Comment: what do you mean? From what I understand, "hardcoded color-values" are like `Color.Blue`, `Color.Red`, etc. and you can create your own `Color` instances with `new Color(red, green, blue)` where each value are in the range of `0-255`. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to replace the this: int red = 255 - (255 * ratio);
int blue = 255 * ratio; with two Color objects. So i f.e. don't generate a blue/red gradient but a green/yellow gradient.

Comment: why did you ask blue/red in your question, then?

Comment: Just to not make it too complicated initially. I first thought i can do it myself bit i can't.

Comment: so, yellow being new objects and green old ones?

Comment: Well let's just define new Object get the Object "Color aColor;" and old Objects get the Object "Color bColor;"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9054/discussion-between-bigteddy-and-yanick-rochon)

Answer (score 0):

Color color = age > 5280 ? Color.RED : age > 1000 ? Color.BLACK : age > 30 ? Color.YouGetTheIdea

Comment: Please tell me you would never nest the ternary operator like that in your code...

Comment: I might...it is compact and clear. But mainly I post instructional examples for teaching.  The originator chooses what works best in his situation.  Some new readers might not have know about this option.  But, usually, I use nn=xx?yy:zz; as you already hoped.

Comment: while I usually like ternary operators when doing simple validations, I think this is over abusing. Especially since `if .. else` blocks are as efficient in this case and produce more readable sources. Smaller code source does not mean faster compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a measure based on the age of each object, either in miliseconds, hours, or perhaps a custom measure based on the above i.e. anything < 1 hr is 1 etc.

That gives you the measure. NOw you could iterate through the objects to find current limits 9min and max) or you could even do it while you calculate the measures: each time sth smaller than min happens, store new min etc.

Now you now the spread. The last thing is to apply colours. Let's say our objects range from 10 ms to 1000 ms. You could split it into 3 regions: 10 - 100, 100 - 500, 500 -1000 for instance and apply colours based on that.